# How to chain include in C++?

Tags: c++

I don't know the proper term for this so pardon my post title. I wanted my workspace clean and organize so I thought maybe its that I should reorganize the file structure of the library I was writing for my game. I have a file structure which looks like this:

```
MyLibrary/include
MyLibrary/src
```

The problem with this is that on the client part, they are oblige to do something like this:

```
#include "MyLibrary/include/myfile.hpp"
```

I wanted it to look like this:

```
#include "MyLibrary/myfile.hpp"
```

How can I achieve this using C++?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to look like `#include "MyLibrary/myfile.hpp"`, make your include directory look like this:

```
MyLibrary/include/MyLibrary/*.hpp
```

Then in whatever build system you are using, add `MyLibrary/include` into the include path.

For example, for GCC you could add `-I local/path/to/include` to your invocation. Have a look at the documentation for your specific build system for instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Include files are looked up into the include directory path (a list of directories). For example with gcc you could use

```
#include "myfile.hpp"
```

and the compile by adding the option `-I`

```
gcc -I MyLibrary/include ...other options...
```

Note that you can provide option `-I` multiple times.

There is no way in compilers I know to however "skip" parts of the path... i.e. to make

```
MyLibrary/myfile.hpp
```

to resolve to

```
MyLibrary/include/myfile.hpp
```